# Access D: as removable drive in Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I have three RaspBerry pi2 running windows 10 IoT.
On two of them I'm able to access drive d: as removable device from my code.
One of them when I run the following code

```
 StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (sdCard == null)
        {
```

I get null for the sdCard - but this happens just for one of three.
And on all devices I can access d: via \myip\d$

Is this a "bug" or did I forget a step when configuring my third device?

Comment: If it was a bug you'd get the same error on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem.

The SD card was created from an existing one using win32diskimager. It looked good except the problem here. After checking bit by bit I found out that the card has a lot of partitions - one with ID 1 and several others with ID 0.
The first partition (ID 1) holds a drive (EFI...) and is marked as active on the original (working) SD card.

On the clone it was not active - Windows 10 IoT booted but drive D: was not included as removable device.
After setting the partition active everything works as expected.